# JavaScript: Map an object to a different structure

Tags: javascript

My application receives data from various source systems. The data are of same nature but different structure. I need to unify the structure and save them into a common repository.

What I'm doing now is as below:

Define a structure mapping between incoming object and output object. For example, for a source object like:

```
{id:'123', message:'hi', from:{id:'user1', name:'John'}},
```

its mapping object is as below:

```
var map = {_id:'id', message:'text', 'from.id':'by.id', 'from.name':'by.name'};
```

Define function as below:

```
function setSubFieldValue(obj, field, value) {
    if(field && obj && value) {
        var i = field.indexOf('\.');
        if( i > 0) {
            var p = field.slice(0, i);
            if(!obj[p]) obj[p] = {}; 
            setSubFieldValue(obj[p], field.slice(i+1), value)
        } else obj[field] = value;
    }
}

function getSubFieldValue(obj, field) {
    if(field) {
        var i = field.indexOf('\.');
        if (i > 0) {
            var p = field.slice(0, i); 
            if(obj[p]) {
                var v = field.slice(i+1);
                return getSubFieldValue(obj[p], v);
            }
        } else return obj[field];
    }
}

function mapObject (srcObj, fieldMap) {
    var obj = {};

    Object.keys(fieldMap).forEach(function(k) {
        var v = getSubFieldValue(srcObj, k);
        if(v) setSubFieldValue(obj, fieldMap[k], v);
    });

    return obj;
};
```

The code does the trick most of the time but have a few drawbacks:

1. Not supporting structures mapping of objects in array. For example,

   ```
   {arrayproperty:[{a:1, b:2}, {a:2, b:3}]}
   ```

   My code above won't allow me to map this arrayproperty a different structure in the target object, like:

   ```
   {newfield:[{field_a:1, field_b:2}, {field_a:2, field_b:3}]}
   ```

   or

   ```
   {newfield_a_0:1, newfield_b_0:2, newfield_a_1:2, newfield_b_1:3}
   ```
2. Using recursive call and not performing well.

I'm wondering if anyone has a similar need and some idea of existing libraries to perform such task elegantly.

Comment: can you explain _Not supporting structures mapping of objects in array._ possibly sample?

Comment: Grundy, thanks for commenting. I have added more details about the point in the post itself now.

Comment: can you provide `map` object for your array example?

Comment: That's the exact problem I want to resolve. I can come out with some notion to handle array, but code will become pretty cumbersome. I'm looking for some existing and well tested solution.

Comment: so, as i see you use this function for only changing fieldName, without changing structure? i'm right?

Comment: Not true. Define a mapping with '.' to change structure. For example, a:'b.c' will map property 'a' of source object to a sub property 'c' of target object's property 'b'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62753/discussion-between-grundy-and-ming).